# Is there a way to create a global setter?

Tags: javascript

What I need is to have a function, which is called every time an assignments is performed, so for example when there is :

```
var a = b;
c = d;
// or even 
for(var i=3...){}
```

I could have a function like :

```
function assigned(nameL, valL, nameR, valR){
}
```

I don't have high hopes for that, I also acknowledge that it may speed things down a lot, but I need it only for debugging purposes.

Comment: No. But there are proxies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @unlucky13, I guess that's the closest one! It will do. Can you turn the comment to an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a global setter?

No.

ECMAScript2015 introduces [Proxy objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which allows you to do "meta programming" but it doesn't work the way you want.

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

Comment: Regardless of the fact that it's not 100% what I want, at least it allows me to track the assignment of arbitrary variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.defineProperty(window, "varname", {set : callbackfunction}};` is the way to go [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I knew about this. I mean how to create a setter for every variable, even those you don't know about? Even those, that are declared in place, like "var a = b" ?